# scrape NBA table without id or class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this NBA all time leader data with BeautifulSoup: https://www.nba.com/stats/alltime-leaders/?SeasonType=Regular%20Season&PerMode=Totals&StatCategory=PTS

How can I scrape all the players? I tried this but it did not work.

```
players = soup.find_all("td", class_="player")
```

I also tried to scrape by table but it did not have id or class:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoh59.png)

Comment: The table data is under the `<nba-stat-table>` tag which is being dynamically loaded (by JS).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to programming. I guess that means I cannot scrap it?

Answer (score 2):

Data is loaded dynamically from another endpoint you can find in the network tab of the browser. Calling that endpoint gives a json response you can reconstruct the table from easily:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?ActiveFlag=No&LeagueID=00&PerMode=Totals&Scope=S&Season=All+Time&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StatCategory=PTS').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(r['resultSet']['rowSet'], columns = r['resultSet']['headers'])
print(df)
```

Comment: But how could you automatically discover that endpoint, from parsing the original page? You have to manually inspect the JS functions inside the <script> tag and figure out the URL.

Comment: I simply opened the network tab <F12> then refreshed the webpage <F5> and filtered the web traffic on XHR and looked through the requests. This endpoint construction is a query string and slow changing.  The params look the same as those I have seen for years.

Comment: ok, you couldn't discover the URL automatically with BeautifulSoup/selenium/scrapy.

Comment: Looks like it's time for me to dig into pandas this time @QHarr.